# Why you can't use pointer to member as a callable / invokeable in range-v3 for_each?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, range-v3

Suppose I have a `bar` and a `foo` structures:

```
struct bar {
    void bar_function() { }
};

struct foo {
    bar* bar_ptr;

    void foo_function() { }
};
```

Now, I'd like to call `bar_function()` on each of `foo`'s `bar_ptr`s from an `std::vector` of `foo`s:

```
std::vector<foo> fooVec;

ranges::for_each(
        fooVec,
        &bar::bar_function,
        &foo::bar_ptr
);
```

This uses *range-v3's projections* - for each `foo`, we take out `bar_ptr` from it and then we call `bar_function` on each of them.

I would assume that the above will work - we can, after all, `std::invoke` a `&bar::bar_function` with a pointer to a `bar` (which we do have - the `bar_ptr`). For the record I know that range-v3 uses `std::invoke` magic to *always do the right thing*, so it surprises me that this fails with the following error:

> ```
> error: no match for call to '(const ranges::for_each_fn) (std::vector<foo>&, void (bar::*)(), bar* foo::*)'
> [...]
> error: no class template named 'apply' in 'struct ranges::detail::enable_if<false>'
> 73 |         using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B>::template apply<T>;
>    |               ^~~~~~~~~~~
> [...]
> ```

I'm not quite sure which part of the error is relevant here - I know that this fails the SFINAE tests, but I do not know why. Is there a reason why the above should fail or is it a bug?

---

Note that, if we replace `&bar::bar_function` with `[](auto bar_ptr) { bar_ptr->bar_function(); }`, the code happily compiles, which is weird, because, due to `std::invoke`'s nature (to "*always do the right thing*"), I fail to see the difference between those two:

```
std::invoke(&bar::bar_function, bar_ptr); // 1

std::invoke([](auto bar_ptr_arg) {        // 2
    bar_ptr_arg->bar_function();
}, bar_ptr);
```

Comment: Seems [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/7TGxGe). What compiler are you using?

Comment: @cigien [Stephan's lastest MinGW](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (GCC 9.2.0) and Range-v3 from Eric Niebler's GitHub from exactly one month ago.

Comment: Probably a bug. Works on regular [gcc9.2](https://godbolt.org/z/3q5ob5) as well.

Comment: @cigien interesting. Can you confirm which range-v3 version godbolt uses? Not sure whether that's the library or the compiler that's behind the problem at my end.

Comment: You can try it with various versions on godbolt. This works on trunk.